# No longer able to bind to global data structures in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I've been using some Ember objects in my code, such as "App.SelectedBlock" to access selected items in lists (a practice that started when I was using Sproutcore years ago) and now it looks like binding to these objects from the Handlebars templates is going to be deprecated and I'm not sure how to go about fixing that. I'm running Ember 1.8.1 and right now it will still work but I'll get "DEPRECATION: Global lookup of App.SelectedBlock from a Handlebars template is deprecated." and I'm pretty sure it's full removed in 1.9.0. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this without having to completely restructure my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a quick example of how you are using App.SelectedBlock on emberjs.jsbin.com? Is `App.SelectedBlock` just a view that extends `Ember.Select` ?

Comment: I was using {{App.SelectedBlock.id}} in my HB templates to access App.SelectedBlock which is an Ember data object, not a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're doing smthing like:

```
{{App.SelectedBlock.id}}
```

You should not call global variables inside Handlebars template. This is a bad practice. But you can do smthing like this:

```
// in your template controller
selectedBlock: function(){
  return Ember.get('App.SelectedBlock');
}.property('App.SelectedBlock')
```

In hbs template:

```
{{selectedBlock.id}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing. I'm doing some complex drag and drop interactions and then updating some data on the side relative to the selected block. In my experience Ember doesn't work well with drag and drop frameworks and so I need to use globals like this to update the data on the side and see the changes populate into the templates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a property on the controller and use **that** instead of looking up `App.SelectedBlock` globally

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  programmers: function(){
    return App.SelectedBlock.get('programmers');
  }.property()
});

App.SelectedBlock = Ember.Object.create({
 programmers: [
   {firstName: "Yehuda", id: 1},
   {firstName: "Tom",    id: 2}
 ]
});
```

Then, in your template you can do:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

   {{view "select"
     content=programmers
     optionValuePath="content.id"
     optionLabelPath="content.firstName"}}
 </script>
```

See a working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fubequ/2/)

Comment: Yup, this is about the same as the other one but the code is a little more complete and maybe easier for others to understand.